# Putting a code block into a html select text attribute

Tags: asp.net, localization, webforms, globalization

I am currently working on a project for a big company and they want me to change their website into a multilingual website with as little refactoring of code as possible. They currently have the following setup for a dropdown list:

```
<select id="selectStatus" runat="server" title="Select Status" class="standardValue" clientidmode="Static">
<option value="optionValue">
selected="selected">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</option>
<option value="Completed">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</option>
<option value="">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</option>
</select>
```

I was wanting to replace the text as a referance eg.

```
<option value="Completed"><%= LanguageResources.CommonStrings.ALERT_HDR_ACCOUNTNO %></option>
```

But this wont work because it wont let me insert a "code block" as the text attribute, is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance, James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you set up a language master table and bind your dropdownlist with it & Use asp:Dropdownlist instead of select.

OR

Simply,

```
List<string> s = new List<String>();
s.Add(LanguageResources.CommonStrings.ALERT_HDR_ACCOUNTNO);
s.Add(LanguageResources.CommonStrings.ALERT_HDR_ACC);
s.Add(LanguageResources.CommonStrings.ALERT_HDR_ACCOUNT);
s.Add(LanguageResources.CommonStrings.ALERT_HDR_NO);
```

Bind this list to dropdown.

Comment: I was considering changing the selects into asp:Dropdownlist but there are a lot of drop downs, its a huge project, and they werent keen on the idea, the binding of the data may be an option though but could I bind that data to a select? or would it have to be an asp control?

Comment: Yes you can add items to select, but its not actually binding it will be inserting items to that inside a loop.